# How to correctly pass an argument from an inbuilt Office enum from Ribbon to VBA Macro?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm using PowerPoint extensively in multiple languages, and I have a macro that changes the language of each box across the presentation. I call the macro with an argument from the Ribbon, passing the argument as a Tag (as I haven't found any other working method, I can't just call sub(argument) in the Ribbon XML). The problem is, that it only works, when I use an explicit numeric argument (ID of a language), and can't use the name from msoLanguageID enum.

Ribbon XML:

```
<button 
id="Lang_UK" 
label="English (UK)" 
size="normal" 
imageMso="SetLanguage"
onAction="langChange"
tag="2057"
/>
```

Control Sub:

```
Public Sub langChange(control As IRibbonControl)
    Call Macros.ChangeSpellCheckLang(control.Tag)
End Sub
```

And the final procedure:

```
Sub ChangeSpellCheckLang(lang As Integer)
(...)
.Text.Range.LanguageID = lang
End Sub
```

This works, but if I change the tag from 2057 to msoLanguageIDEnglishUK I get an error (13) Type mismatch. I tried changing the final procedure to lang as String or Variant, but I keep getting the same error. I know that msoLanguageIDEnglishUK would work, as previously my final procedure didn't use an argument - instead I just explicitly set ...Text.Range.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUK and it worked.

So, how can I avoid hardcoding language IDs, while still being able to pass them as arguments for the procedure from the Ribbon?

// EDIT:
What is the most surprising part, the error is thrown in langChange Sub in

```
Call Macros.ChangeSpellCheckLang(control.Tag)
```

Comment: Please tell us (or better, use the [edit] link below the question to add it directly to the question): Which line of code causes the error? My guess would be it comes from `ChangeSpellCheckLang` because the numerical equivalents of Office enumerations are of data type `Long`, not `Integer`.

Comment: I changed the input param for `ChangeSpellCheckLang` to `Long`, but the problem still exists.
When I highlight the problematic line it shows that `control.Tag = "msoLanguageIDEnglishUK"` so I'm wondering if maybe the quotation marks could be the issue and that the constant is not resolved, but passed on as a string.

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. The `tag` property is a string. VBA will coerce a numeric string to a number without explicit conversion. But the same will not apply to an enumeration. Why can't you write the numerical equivalent instead of the name? If you need to use the name  you'd need a "look up" - something that provides the numerical equivalent for a language string.

Comment: Maybe I'm just over-sensitive, but I think that hardcoding a numeric ID is not the best practice, especially, when I have an in-built list `msoLanguageID`.

Comment: Per Cindy's suggestion, you could use something like Call Macros.ChangeSpellCheckLang(LangIDToLong(control.Tag)) and write a simple LangIDToLong function that takes the language ID constant name as input and returns the equivalent Long value.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'm quite new to VBA, so I'm not sure if I'm able to write a proper function to retrieve the constant values (it would look like a multiple case statement or some lookup) so I'll jsut stick to the numeric values.
To my understanding these are global, constant, and reliable numeric representations of specific languages and they are unlikely to change for example with a next Office release, right?

Comment: @vvilku "To my understanding ..."  Yes, that's correct. A new release might add new constants (which older versions wouldn't understand) but constants and their values won't change from one version to the next.  A function to return the correct value for strings would be quite simple to write.  Let us know if you'd rather go that way.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I have 6 languages to cover, so it's not an issue, however for study purposes, I'd be interested in how to properly do that - is `msoLanguageID` structure accessible somehow?

Comment: Easily:  in the VBA IDE, press F2 to open the object browser, search for msoLanguageID.  That'll lead you to a list of all the possible IDs. Click on the one you want to get the value of the constant. There's a fairly recent listing of all of them here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.MsoLanguageID

Comment: I know that, I was rather interested if there is a way to write a VBA function that returns the number by reading the msoLanguageID itself, instead of me writing a function with `case when msoLanguageIDEnglishUK Then Return 2057` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The msoLanguage constants are part of the suite of Office applications. However, I recently was using some other enum constants between the applications like shape placeholder types in PPT. For my purposes I needed to get the constant name from the value so I used a current enum list and a little regex to quickly format a list that creates a collection. I've quickly done the same here for the languages. The first line declares the collection and the last `colLang("1130") ' return msoLanguageIDYoruba` is an example of retrieving the enum name from the value.

```
Dim colLang As New Collection
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDAfrikaans", "1078" ' The Afrikaans language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDAlbanian", "1052" ' The Albanian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDAmharic", "1118" ' The Amharic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabic", "1025" ' The Arabic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicAlgeria", "5121" ' The Arabic Algeria language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicBahrain", "15361" ' The Arabic Bahrain language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicEgypt", "3073" ' The Arabic Egypt language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicIraq", "2049" ' The Arabic Iraq language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicJordan", "11265" ' The Arabic Jordan language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicKuwait", "13313" ' The Arabic Kuwait language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicLebanon", "12289" ' The Arabic Lebanon language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicLibya", "4097" ' The Arabic Libya language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicMorocco", "6145" ' The Arabic Morocco language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicOman", "8193" ' The Arabic Oman language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicQatar", "16385" ' The Arabic Qatar language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicSyria", "10241" ' The Arabic Syria language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicTunisia", "7169" ' The Arabic Tunisia language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicUAE", "14337" ' The Arabic UAE language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArabicYemen", "9217" ' The Arabic Yemen language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDArmenian", "1067" ' The Armenian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDAssamese", "1101" ' The Assamese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDAzeriCyrillic", "2092" ' The Azerbaijani Cyrillic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDAzeriLatin", "1068" ' The Azerbaijani Latin language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBasque", "1069" ' Basque (Basque)
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBelgianDutch", "2067" ' The Belgian Dutch language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBelgianFrench", "2060" ' The Belgian French language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBengali", "1093" ' The Bengali language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBosnian", "4122" ' The Bosnian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBosnianBosniaHerzegovinaCyrillic", "8218" ' The Bosnian Bosnia Herzegovina Cyrillic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBosnianBosniaHerzegovinaLatin", "5146" ' The Bosnian Bosnia Herzegovina Latin language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBrazilianPortuguese", "1046" ' The Portuguese (Brazil) language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBulgarian", "1026" ' The Bulgarian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDBurmese", "1109" ' The Burmese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDByelorussian", "1059" ' The Belarusian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDCatalan", "1027" ' The Catalan language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDCherokee", "1116" ' The Cherokee language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDChineseHongKongSAR", "3076" ' The Chinese Hong Kong SAR language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDChineseMacaoSAR", "5124" ' The Chinese Macao SAR language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDChineseSingapore", "4100" ' The Chinese Singapore language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDCroatian", "1050" ' The Croatian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDCzech", "1029" ' The Czech language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDDanish", "1030" ' The Danish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDDivehi", "1125" ' The Divehi language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDDutch", "1043" ' The Dutch language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEdo", "1126" ' The Edo language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishAUS", "3081" ' The English AUS language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishBelize", "10249" ' The English Belize language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishCanadian", "4105" ' The English Canadian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishCaribbean", "9225" ' The English Caribbean language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishIndonesia", "14345" ' The English Indonesia language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishIreland", "6153" ' The English Ireland language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishJamaica", "8201" ' The English Jamaica language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishNewZealand", "5129" ' The English NewZealand language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishPhilippines", "13321" ' The English Philippines language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishSouthAfrica", "7177" ' The English South Africa language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishTrinidadTobago", "11273" ' The English Trinidad Tobago language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishUK", "2057" ' The English UK language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishUS", "1033" ' The English US language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEnglishZimbabwe", "12297" ' The English Zimbabwe language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDEstonian", "1061" ' The Estonian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFaeroese", "1080" ' The Faeroese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFarsi", "1065" ' The Farsi language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFilipino", "1124" ' The Filipino language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFinnish", "1035" ' The Finnish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrench", "1036" ' The French language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchCameroon", "11276" ' The French Cameroon language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchCanadian", "3084" ' The French Canadian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchCotedIvoire", "12300" ' The French Coted Ivoire language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchHaiti", "15372" ' The French Haiti language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchLuxembourg", "5132" ' The French Luxembourg language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchMali", "13324" ' The French Mali language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchMonaco", "6156" ' The French Monaco language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchMorocco", "14348" ' The French Morocco language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchReunion", "8204" ' The French Reunion language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchSenegal", "10252" ' The French Senegal language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrenchWestIndies", "7180" ' The French West Indies language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFranchCongoDRC", "9228" ' The French Congo DRC language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFrisianNetherlands", "1122" ' The Frisian Netherlands language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDFulfulde", "1127" ' The Fulfulde language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGaelicIreland", "2108" ' The Irish (Ireland) language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGaelicScotland", "1084" ' The Scottish Gaelic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGalician", "1110" ' The Galician language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGeorgian", "1079" ' The Georgian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGerman", "1031" ' The German language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGermanAustria", "3079" ' The German Austria language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGermanLiechtenstein", "5127" ' The German Liechtenstein language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGermanLuxembourg", "4103" ' The German Luxembourg language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGreek", "1032" ' The Greek language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGuarani", "1140" ' The Guarani language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDGujarati", "1095" ' The Gujarati language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDHausa", "1128" ' The Hausa language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDHawaiian", "1141" ' The Hawaiian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDHebrew", "1037" ' The Hebrew language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDHindi", "1081" ' The Hindi language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDHungarian", "1038" ' The Hungarian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDIbibio", "1129" ' The Ibibio language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDIcelandic", "1039" ' The Icelandic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDIgbo", "1136" ' The Igbo language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDIndonesian", "1057" ' The Indonesian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDInuktitut", "1117" ' The Inuktitut language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDItalian", "1040" ' The Italian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDJapanese", "1041" ' The Japanese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKannada", "1099" ' The Kannada language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKanuri", "1137" ' The Kanuri language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKashmiri", "1120" ' The Kashmiri language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKashmiriDevanagari", "2144" ' The Kashmiri Devanagari language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKazakh", "1087" ' The Kazakh language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKhmer", "1107" ' The Khmer language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKirghiz", "1088" ' The Kirghiz language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKonkani", "1111" ' The Konkani language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKorean", "1042" ' The Korean language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDKyrgyz", "1088" ' The Kyrgyz language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDLao", "1108" ' The Lao language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDLatin", "1142" ' The Latin language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDLatvian", "1062" ' The Latvian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDLithuanian", "1063" ' The Lithuanian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMacedoninanFYROM", "1071" ' The Macedonian FYROM language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMalayalam", "1100" ' The Malayalam language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMalayBruneiDarussalam", "2110" ' The Malay Brunei Darussalam language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMalaysian", "1086" ' The Malaysian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMaltese", "1082" ' The Maltese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDManipuri", "1112" ' The Manipuri language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMaori", "1153" ' The Maori language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMarathi", "1102" ' The Marathi language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMexicanSpanish", "2058" ' The Mexican Spanish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMixed",   "-2"    ' The Mixed language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDMongolian", "1104" ' The Mongolian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDNepali", "1121" ' The Nepali language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDNone", "0" ' No language specified
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDNoProofing", "1024" ' No proofing
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDNorwegianBokmol", "1044" ' The Norwegian Bokmol language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDNorwegianNynorsk", "2068" ' The Norwegian Nynorsk language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDOriya", "1096" ' The Odia language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDOromo", "1138" ' The Oromo language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDPashto", "1123" ' The Pashto language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDPolish", "1045" ' The Polish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDPortuguese", "2070" ' The Portuguese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDPunjabi", "1094" ' The Punjabi language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDQuechuaBolivia", "1131" ' The Quechua Bolivia language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDQuechuaEcuador", "2155" ' The Quechua Ecuador language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDQuechuaPeru", "3179" ' The Quechua Peru language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDRhaetoRomanic", "1047" ' The Rhaeto Romanic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDRomanian", "1048" ' The Romanian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDRomanianMoldova", "2072" ' The Romanian Moldova language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDRussian", "1049" ' The Russian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDRussianMoldova", "2073" ' The Russian Moldova language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSamiLappish", "1083" ' The Sami Lappish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSanskrit", "1103" ' The Sanskrit language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSepedi", "1132" ' The Sepedi language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSerbianBosniaHerzegovinaCyrillic", "7194" ' The Serbian Bosnia Herzegovina Cyrillic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSerbianBosniaHerzegovinaLatin", "6170" ' The Serbian Bosnia Herzegovina Latin language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSerbianCyrillic", "3098" ' The Serbian Cyrillic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSerbianLatin", "2074" ' The Serbian Latin language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSesotho", "1072" ' The Sesotho language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSimplifiedChinese", "2052" ' The Simplified Chinese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSindhi", "1113" ' The Sindhi language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSindhiPakistan", "2137" ' The Sindhi Pakistan language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSinhalese", "1115" ' The Sinhalese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSlovak", "1051" ' The Slovak language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSlovenian", "1060" ' The Slovenian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSomali", "1143" ' The Somali language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSorbian", "1070" ' The Sorbian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanish", "1034" ' The Spanish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishArgentina", "11274" ' The Spanish Argentina language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishBolivia", "16394" ' The Spanish Bolivia language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishChile", "13322" ' The Spanish Chile language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishColombia", "9226" ' The Spanish Colombia language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishCostaRica", "5130" ' The Spanish Costa Rica language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishDominicanRepublic", "7178" ' The Spanish Dominican Republic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishEcuador", "12298" ' The Spanish Ecuador language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishElSalvador", "17418" ' The Spanish El Salvador language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishGuatemala", "4106" ' The Spanish Guatemala language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishHonduras", "18442" ' The Spanish Honduras language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishModernSort", "3082" ' The Spanish Modern Sort language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishNicaragua", "19466" ' The Spanish Nicaragua language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishPanama", "6154" ' The Spanish Panama language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishParaguay", "15370" ' The Spanish Paraguay language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishPeru", "10250" ' The Spanish Peru language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishPuertoRico", "20490" ' The Spanish Puerto Rico language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishUruguay", "14346" ' The Spanish Uruguay language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSpanishVenezuela", "8202" ' The Spanish Venezuela language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSutu", "1072" ' The Sutu language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSwahili", "1089" ' The Swahili language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSwedish", "1053" ' The Swedish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSwedishFinland", "2077" ' The Swedish Finland language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSwissFrench", "4108" ' The Swiss French language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSwissGerman", "2055" ' The Swiss German language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSwissItalian", "2064" ' The Swiss Italian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDSyriac", "1114" ' The Syriac language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTajik", "1064" ' The Tajik language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTamazight", "1119" ' The Tamazight language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTamazightLatin", "2143" ' The Tamazight Latin language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTamil", "1097" ' The Tamil language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTatar", "1092" ' The Tatar language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTelugu", "1098" ' The Telugu language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDThai", "1054" ' The Thai language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTibetan", "1105" ' The Tibetan language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTigrignaEritrea", "2163" ' The Tigrigna Eritrea language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTigrignaEthiopic", "1139" ' The Tigrigna Ethiopic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTraditionalChinese", "1028" ' The Traditional Chinese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTsonga", "1073" ' The Tsonga language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTswana", "1074" ' The Tswana language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTurkish", "1055" ' The Turkish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDTurkmen", "1090" ' The Turkmen language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDUkrainian", "1058" ' The Ukrainian language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDUrdu", "1056" ' The Urdu language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDUzbekCyrillic", "2115" ' The Uzbek Cyrillic language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDUzbekLatin", "1091" ' The Uzbek Latin language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDVenda", "1075" ' The Venda language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDVietnamese", "1066" ' The Vietnamese language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDWelsh", "1106" ' The Welsh language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDXhosa", "1076" ' The Xhosa language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDYi", "1144" ' The Yi language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDYiddish", "1085" ' The Yiddish language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDYoruba", "1130" ' The Yoruba language
colLang.Add "msoLanguageIDZulu", "1077" ' The Zulu language

colLang("1130") ' Would return msoLanguageIDYoruba
```